# Javascript How to get # id from the end of the HTML URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor

I have a webpage with some links on it

```
<a href="#glass">Glass</a>
<a href="#plastic">Plastic</a>
<a href="#ceramic">Ceramic</a>
```

that change options on the page.
I want to get the #glass, #plastic or #ceramic in javascript at the end of the URL, but I want the option to work from other links from other websites.

Comment: document.location.hash

Comment: While [`document.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is the answer to your question I suspect you might also be interested in CSS' [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the specific id, use this line of code:

```
var id = window.location.toString().split('#')[1]
```

It will get the whole URL (example: `http://example.site/home#contact`) and, since # is a unique character in each URL, you can use `string.split()` to get the part of the string that is after the #, in this case, `contact`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `window.location` is an object, you cannot directly use `split()`, you will first have to  use `toString()`, or you can also use the dedicated property, like in @HaukurHaf comment : `window.location.hash`